# Gauss Bonnet theorem and general relativity

Tags: differential-geometry, general-relativity

In the text : Vector calculus - Marsden, 
Gauss Bonnet theorem can be the motivation of the two dimensional 
Einstein Hilbert action. But, I could not find well these contents
in many texts.

Is there any good reference about the relation between Gauss bonnet theorem
and the 2-dimensional General relativity?